# Microsoft Graph: Pagination in 'Get Organization' api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use  'Get /organization' api to fetch the tenant name, tenant id and list of domains in the tenant. If there are many domains (say 300-400) in the tenant, would all of them be included in the response? or would the response be paginated? In that case how should I handle pagination?

My app is Java based and I am directly using the REST interfaces.

Comment: Paging is documented @ https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/paging

Comment: Thanks Marc. I had a look at the paging documentation. It suggest to use '$top' query parameter. The output of 'Get /organization' is a little bit different. It returns many information. The list of domain names is only a part of the response available under property 'verifiedDomains'. How would the '$top' parameter apply in this case. The page also says not all resources support paging. Wondering if 'organization' supports paging? If it does not will i get all domains or would it be truncated? I am trying to use this as i need tenant id and name also in addition to domains.

Comment: It a resource doesn't support paging, it will simply return all of the results (regardless of length). If it supports paging, you will receive a `nextLink` to the next page as part of the results.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the explanation. It is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing issues getting all the data back?  AFAIK Organization is a singleton, so specifying $top won't help here.  My assumption is that you will get all the data back in the single response.

Hope this helps,